# How do I select text in right order in PDFs like this

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-reader

I work with chemical safety data sheets. My job is to transfer PDFs into a database by copy/pasting.

I have problems with some types of PDF files, like this one: https://www.jotun.com/Datasheets/Download?url=%2FSDS%2FSDS__545__Jotun%20Anti-skid__Nor__NO.pdf

When I try to select the text, it selects it in a seemingly random order, like this:
[image: selected text]

I have tried using different PDF editors, but none of them seems to be able to select the text in the right order.

I would really appreciate help from someone here, as it would make a huge improvement in my workflow.

Comment: Is that on Windows?

Comment: Yes, it is on Windows. I haven't tried with another OS

Answer (score 2):

Linux:

```
$ link="https://www.jotun.com/Datasheets/Download?url=%2FSDS%2FSDS__545__Jotun%20Anti-skid__Nor__NO.pdf"
tempfile=/tmp/Download
$ wget    -o ${tempfile}.pdf "$link"         \
&& pdftotext ${tempfile}.pdf ${tempfile}.txt \
&& less      ${tempfile}.txt                 \
&& rm        ${tempfile}.*
```

*The above is easy to convert into a bash script.*

Text displayed by `less`:

```
I samsvar med forskriften (EC) nr. 453/2010 (REACH), vedlegg II, som endret av forskriften (EU) nr. 2015/830

SIKKERHETSDATABLAD
Jotun Anti-skid
AVSNITT 1: Identifikasjon av stoffet/stoffblandingen og selskapet/foretaket
1.1 Produktidentifikator
Produktnavn

: Jotun Anti-skid

EC nummer
CAS nummer

: 215-691-6
: 1344-28-1

Produktkode

: 545

Produktbeskrivelse
Type produkt
Andre identifiseringsmåter

: Inert materiale.
: Fast.
: Ikke kjent.

Produktregistreringsnummer : Under anmeldelse

1.2 Relevante, identifiserte bruksområder for stoffet eller blandingen, og ikke-anbefalt bruk
Identifisert bruk
Brukes i overflatebelegg - Industrielt bruk
Brukes i overflatebelegg - Profesjonell bruk
Industrielle anvendelser, Faglige applikasjoner.
...
```

*Windows: Install and use "[WSL](https://www.google.se/search?q=windows%20subsystem%20linux)" to be able to use the above.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It interesting to see that data, but the text should be copied like this:

1.1 Produktidentifikator
Produktnavn: Jotun Anti-skid
EC nummer: 215-691-6
CAS nummer: 1344-28-1
Produktkode: 545
Produktbeskrivelse: Inert materiale.
Type produkt: Fast.
Andre identifiseringsmåter: Ikke kjent.
Produktregistreringsnummer : Under anmeldelse

Like it looks in the screenshot.

Comment: Well, I would guess will have hard to find it "packaged" like that. From experience I know that no two safety datasheets look the same. There is always at least one detail differing in the formatting, i.e. it is hard to build a simple tool for (extracting) them all. I believe they need to be provided in e.g. an XML-format - that everyone uses.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is the way that the PDF was built.
The author had the problem of aligning the two columns, and took the strange
solution of dividing the text into two vertical text boxes.

Below is a screenshot of the PDF when displayed in Adobe Acrobat Pro in Edit mode.
You can clearly see the text boxes.
Notice what happens when I try to select text across the two boxes:

[image]

You will see that the selection can only be done inside one box at a time.
Adobe Acrobat Pro will not let one select text across textboxes, only inside one box.
When you are trying to select across boxes, any PDF viewer is liable to do
weird things, as you have discovered.

I have tried in Adobe Acrobat Pro to convert the file to various formats
that may be easier to select.
The only save-mode for which this worked was "Text (plain)".
Selecting within this text file did work as expected:

[image]

The answer in then in finding the right PDF-to-text convertor.
I have written once such a product, and mine would have also failed on
this PDF, as it would have given all of the text from the first textbox
followed by all the text from the second. Knowing that the two textboxes
need to be divided into parts that are to be combined into lines is far
from trivial.

As a service to you, I have posted the entire text of this PDF
[on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BmRU0en5).
I didn't make the pastebin permanent, so you should not wait in downloading
it. Hope that this helps.